# Food calories by type and weight

Tags: nutrition

How can I estimate the calories in food by weight and type. For example, if I have X ounces of meat, approximately how calories is that? Or, if I have X ounces of a starch (like a tuber) how many calories is that?

I am looking for approximate formulas, not exact amounts.

Answer (score 2):

In order to know how many calories some food sample contains, you need to know exactly how much of that sample is protein, fat, and carbohydrate. This [PDF](http://www.dining.ucla.edu/housing_site/dining/SNAC_pdf/CaloriesCount.pdf) from UCLA gives a breakdown of the calories per gram of those components:

> - Carbohydrate = 4 calories per gram
> - Protein = 4 calories per gram
> - Alcohol = 7 calories per gram
> - Fat = 9 calories per gram

Once you know what these are, the math is fairly straightforward; just multiply each and then add. If there are 5 grams of carbs, then totals calories from carbs equals 5 x 4 = 20; if 6 grams of protein, then 4 x 6 = 24; and so on.
Starch is a carbohydrate. But for your other example of "*meat*", you'd need to know the breakdown of that particular meat, so you couldn't just say X amount of meat has y amount of protein, z amount of carbohydrate, and z amount of fat. Each meat is different. That said, the breakdown of each kind of meat (i.e. chicken, lean beef, pork, etc.) is probably close enough that you could get a ballpark figure for whatever kind of meat you're interested in.

Comment: Very useful info, thanks very much. Is there some reason you did not upvote my question?

Comment: @TylerDurden, if you accept my answer, your rep gets increased, so I didn't see the point. However, if it makes you feel better...